# Android Mobile/Device as a BLE GATT Peripheral & Central Simultaneously

Tags: java, android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, gatt

I want to make two Android apps using `BLE & GATT Protocol`. Implementation like that role of the first app is `GATT Client` and the role of the second app is `GATT Server` ( or *how to make the mobile phone a GATT Peripheral?*) using Kotlin/Java. Both the apps will execute on a same mobile device and when I send an advertisement from one app the second app will receive this broadcast.

Is there any tutorial or article link other than the android official document where it is clearly explained? Or how should i implement this?

Answer (score 1):

You can implement GATT client and GATT server concurrently. In most cases you don't need to know that the same app or another app runs the other role as well, so just develop like you usually would have done if you only implemented one role. Just keep in mind that a GATT client cannot communicate with a GATT server on the same device; it must be another physical device.